# how do I create bean at application startup before loading spring context?

Tags: java, spring

I want to create datasource bean programmatically depending on args passed from user then

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {     
        //TODO load proper configs depending on args 
        //TODO initiate dataSource bean with UN and PS in args
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "config/applicationContext-common.xml" );
   }
}
```

I've done a little googling already and found that I have to create a post processor bean that creates a data source bean and programmatically configures it using the fetched data.
What I'd like to see is a real example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the code below, it should inject dataSource before wiring.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {     
        //TODO load proper configs depending on args 
        //TODO initiate dataSource bean with UN and PS in args
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/applicationContext-common.xml") {
          protected void prepareBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
           super.prepareBeanFactory(beanFactory);
           beanFactory.registerSingleton("dataSource", dataSource);
          }
        };
   }
}
```

Comment: well, this means if I have another bean which depends on `dataSource` and has an init method that uses `dataSource` I will have to programmatically register it as well before refreshing the context and so on ?

Comment: @MustafaZidan no, init won't be called until you invoke `refresh()`. You should be able to include beans depending on "dataSource" in your xml.

Comment: aha, got it , this was helpful :)

Comment: there is a broplem in the above solution is that I need to to call `refresh()` at least once before I can use `registerSinglton` as it throws the following exception `BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext` and if I do so the dataSource bean remains unknown and cannot use `@autowire`

Comment: so I've to extend `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` in order to register pragmatically created beans in the application startup, or I can create a `beanFactory`, register datasource bean then add it application context before I refresh

Comment: @MustafaZidan The problem is spring singletons are eagerly initialized by default. This means all their dependencies must be resolved while context is being initialized and your data source must be available already. Unfortunately it turns out you cannot register a singleton easily before bean factory is prepared so I had to resort to anonymous subclass. Maybe there is an easier solution for this, I didn't dig really deep. Refresh first prepares bean factory with a protected method, then instantiates singleton, there are no finer-grained public methods.